# How to get currently focus Tab name in React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using a tab navigator in react navigation. I want to detect currently focus tab when I'm changing the tabs.
Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm using:
 - react-native: 0.57.4, react-navigation: 2.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

```
class MyScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
      tabBarOnPress({ navigation, defaultHandler }) {

        navigation.state.params.onTabFocus('tab_name');

        defaultHandler();
      }
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      onTabFocus: this.getCurrentTab
    });
  }

  getCurrentTab = (tabName) => {
    console.log("current tab >>>>>>", tabName);
  };
}
```

/////////// Second solution ///////////////

Can use [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) Component to subscribe to these navigation events.

- onWillFocus : before focusing a tab
- onDidFocus : after focusing a tab
- onWillBlur : before losing focus on a tab
- onDidBlur : after losing focus on a tab